# which event is triggered for another page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I wanted to know that which events are triggered when there is a page transition from suppose a.html to b.html.
I would like to bind a date property as well as get a session value through ajax when page b.html is getting loaded from a.html.

I have tried pageinit and pagecreate events. When i refresh the b.html then only these two events are triggered.

Please Help.

Thanks & Regards,
Vineet M

Comment: just give me the event which is triggered.ajax one is understood. but how will assign datepicker. I have used $(document).ready(function(){ $("#date").datepicker(); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for `pageshow` and `pagehide` events. Check [in the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html).

```
$( 'div' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event, ui){
  alert( 'This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});

$( 'div' ).live( 'pagehide',function(event, ui){
  alert( 'This page was just shown: '+ ui.nextPage);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but still its not working :(. May I put the code in order to understand

Comment: Yes, please. That may help :)

Comment: $(document).live("#mainpage2","pageshow",function(){
 $("#date").datepicker();
 var dataURLm = "http://localhost:8080/project/mydb?op=session"
 $.ajax({
  url:dataURLm,
  type:"post",
  datatype:"json",
  success: function(jsonData12){
   
  },
  eroor:function(error){
   window.open("login.html",_self,false);
  },
 });
 alert("pageshow Event");
});</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainpage2" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
</div>
<form id="frm">
<div data-role="content">
 <div id="dateDiv">
  <label for="date">Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="date" name="date_v"></div>

Comment: sorry for the mess i am a novice .

Comment: Have you tried writing `$("#mainpage2").live("pageshow", function(){...});`?

Answer (score 1):

I just carried out some research on that particular topic.

The following events are called when transitioning from page A to page B:

- pagebeforechange
- pagebeforeload
- pagebeforecreate
- pagecreate
- pageinit
- pageload
- pagebeforechange (yes, again)
- pagebeforeshow
- pageshow
- pagechange

You can check that by yourself with the following code:

```
$(document).delegate('#pageId','pagebeforeshow', function(event) {
    console.log('pagebeforeshow');
});

$(document).delegate('#pageId','pagebeforecreate', function(event) {
    console.log('pagebeforecreate');
});

$(document).delegate('#pageId','pagecreate', function(event) {
    console.log('pagecreate');
});

$(document).delegate('#pageId','pageinit', function(event) {
    console.log('pageinit');
});

$(document).delegate('#pageId','pageshow', function(event) {
    console.log('pageshow');
});

$(document).bind('pagebeforeload', function(event) {
    console.log('pagebeforeload');
});

$(document).bind('pageload', function(event) {
    console.log('pageload');
});

$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(event) {
    console.log('pagebeforechange');
});

$(document).bind('pagechange', function(event) {
    console.log('pagechange');
});
```